# Multiple accessors for same value in c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, accessor

I have simple scenario where I have `AnotherTest` value based on `Test` value. This works fine most of the time so that whenever I provide `Test` I am sure to get `AnotherTest` easily.

```
public sealed class Transaction {
    public string Test { get;set; }
    public string AnotherTest{
        get {
            int indexLiteryS = Test.IndexOf("S");
            return Test.Substring(indexLiteryS, 4);
        }
    }
}
```

However I wanted to be able to also `set` `AnotherTest` value and be able to read it without having to provide `Test` value. Is this possible? So kinda 2 types of `get` based which way it was set. I know I could create `3rdTest` but I have some methods that use `AnotherTest` and other fields and I would have to write overloads of that methods.

Edit:

I read some file supplied by bank. I cut it in pieces put some stuff in `Test` value and every other field (AnotherTest and similar) of the Transaction gets filled automatically. 
However later on I would like to read Transaction from SQL that is already in nice format so I don't need to provide `Test` to get the rest of the fields. I would like to set those fields with `set` and then be able to use `get` without setting `Test` value.

Comment: Your `AnotherTest` getter is currently recursive, and also mentions `LiniaTransakcjiString` - are those two meant to actually use `Test`?

Comment: Yes both are test (copy/pasted) but inserted wrong value

Comment: So what would it logically *mean* to set AnotherTest without there being a Test value? It doesn't help that you've given us no real indication of what these properties are intended to represent.

Comment: @KevinCoulombe it was a copy/paste/hand edit error. Typo :-)

Comment: Based on the information given, these properties best implemented as methods as they will convey design decision better.

Comment: I edited my question to provide more insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, like so:

```
public string Test { get; set; }

public string AnotherTest
{
   get
   {
      if(_anotherTest != null || Test == null)
         return _anotherTest;

      int indexLiteryS = Test.IndexOf("S")
      return Test.Substring(indexLiteryS, 4);
   }
   set { _anotherTest = value; }
}
private string _anotherTest;
```

That getter could also be expressed as

```
return (_anotherTest != null || Test == null)
    ? _anotherTest
    : Test.Substring(Test.IndexOf("S"), 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do what you want it to do:

```
public sealed class Transaction {
    public string Test { get;set; }
    public string AnotherTest{
        get {
            if (_anotherTest != null)
            {
                return _anotherTest;
            }
            else
            {
                int indexLiteryS = Test.IndexOf("S");
                return Test.Substring(indexLiteryS, 4);
            }
        }
        set {
            _anotherTest = value;
        }
    }
    private string _anotherTest = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest turning the problem over.

It sounds like you're dealing with a big field and subfields within it.  Instead, how about promoting those subfields to fields and constructing/deconstructing the big field when it's accessed.

Comment: I am deconstructing the big fields provided for me in the file from bank. When it's saved into SQL in clean format it doesn't seem to be a good idea to try to read SQL and construct the same type that bank is sending the information in as it seems overkill and unnecessary job for code.